# Margin:auto's function in centering a div within a div

Tags: html, css

I was searching the archives and came across the following article about [how to center a div within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div), where the solution was to apply the following styles to the inner div:

```
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The answer states that the `margin:auto` is what causes the centering. How exactly does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:auto;` is specifically designed to automatically set a margin, usually for the purpose of centering an element.  It actually only works on the left and right margins.  Using `margin:auto;` is shorthand for the following:

```
{ margin:0px auto 0px auto; }
```

And to spell that out further:

```
{ margin-top:0px; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:auto; }
```

Check out the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins).

Answer (score 0):

It basically solves the equation `margin = ("outer-width" - "inner-width") / 2` and sets the result to the margin value.

The result is, that the margin of your inner div is the same on both sides and its overall width (width + 2×border + 2×margin) fills exactly your outer div. So it's body is centered.